# Multiple indexes on the same table

Tags: mysql, indexing, schema

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feeds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `external_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `image_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9046 ;
```

I am creating indexes on `external_id` and `location_id` they are meant to be used separately for different queries that effect the table. I understand that MySQL will have to rebuild the indexes every time a record is added or updated or deleted. What I cannot figure out is if updating the `name` field of a record in this table will cause either or both indexes to be rebuilt. Also, I am wondering, it is the case that these two separate indexes can exist on this table without effecting each others performance negatively? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes are not "rebuilt", but they are updated. Altering data in columns that are not indexed should not result in any re-indexing activity.

Comment: This would still mean that on any insert to this table the index must be re-written every time? Is there a good resource that could explain this type of specific index stuff? Thank you for your help, tadman.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM, the MySQL Storage Engine you're using, will update the indexes every time a row is updated. Meaning that the more indexes a table has, the more time it takes to insert, update or delete rows from that table. But queries should run faster. You might want to make use of EXPLAIN to the the query plan.